How can I sign in a user in Firebase using Google in Unity running a remote service?
I'm making a game in Unity for mobile (specifically Android) and I'm using Firebase to store all my users. I'm having an ASP.NET remote service hosted on AWS Lambda that handles some of the game logic that requires server authority including access to the database and to the sign up process.
From what I could gather from the documentation, I need a "Google Id Token" and a "Google Access Token":
Firebase.Auth.Credential credential = Firebase.Auth.GoogleAuthProvider.GetCredential(googleIdToken, googleAccessToken); 
Unfortunately I have no idea what these are or where am I supposed to get them or what they are so I'd like to know whats the correct procedure to sign up using these tokens and if I need the firebase SDK to run in Unity or can I somehow move it on the remote service so all the client has to do is a bunch of HTTP requests.
Thanks!
